# Dynamic InnerFade with JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi guyz I'm trying to implement the InnerFade JQuery on my page but I'm a little bit confuse how to do it..
This is my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.innerfade.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
function(){
$('#time').innerfade({
animationtype: 'slide',
speed: 750,
timeout: 2000,
type: 'random',
containerheight: '1em'
}); 
});
</script>

<body>
<div class="page">
<div id="header">
<br />
<div id="title">

</div>
<div id="menucontainer">
<ul id="menu">

</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div id="main">
@RenderBody()
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

(Problem): I dont know where to put the `<ul id="time">` since I'm using a dynamic page.. please help me guyz.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling $('#time').innerfade() in document.ready is going to try to trigger your fade immediately after the page loads, and if your #time element does not yet exist, which according to your html it does not, then nothing is going to happen.

If what you are trying to achieve is "insert the element dynamically and have it fade in instead of just 'pop in'",

First insert `<ul id="time" style="display:none">`, then call $('#time').innerfade().

Comment: Another question how will I have it fade by table? because as of now it fade but one after the other.. thanks.

Comment: @bot I can't understand what you are asking, try making a new question.  Remember to be detailed in the question and give a good but not super long example of your code.  Party On.

Comment: nvermind dude I've already solve it myself :) I Just rearrange the structure of my @foreach since im using two foreach then that solves the problem.. but still thanks for sharing your idea with me.